# DateTimeParseException in Swagger Autogen Java Client

Tags: java, gson, swagger, iso

I have an autogenerated Java client from a Swagger file for a service's API. I put the Swagger file in the Swagger editor and downloaded the Java client and then installed it to my local maven repo which I then pulled into my maven project to use. (Swagger SOP so far.)

All of my requests work fine until I perform a get request for an object that contains an ISO date without the Z to indicate UTC (e.g. `2018-02-07T21:23:37.177` doesn't work, but `2017-07-18T03:41:57.427Z` works).

The exception I get is:

> org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeParseException: Text
>   '2018-02-07T21:23:37.177' could not be parsed at index 23

This happens in the Gson.java class (gson 2.8.1) that is packaged with the autogenerated swagger client, in the `fromJson` method when it attempts to deserialize the date. I walked through the threeten `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` and it looks like it parses okay, then when it's unwinding its parse position it suddenly sets the position to `-24` and adds the error position which throws the error.

I'm wondering if one of these may be the cause or if this gives anyone some ideas for insight:

- the date itself, which appears to conform to the ISO standard
- the service's Swagger file, how the service describes their API (the model's date field seems fine, `format: date-time` and `type: string`
- Swagger's autogenerated client
- the GSON library (v2.8.1) the autogenerated Swagger code depends on
- the threeten library (v1.3.5) the autogenerated Swagger code depends on

Comment: The date string without a time zone (e.g. `Z`), is incomplete. 9:23 PM in Eastern time zone is not the same time as 9:23 PM in Pacific time zone, or Central Europe time zone. `Z` explicitly marks the date string as representing 9:23 PM is UTC time zone.

Comment: Your string is 23 chars long, so it does seem to be missing a `Z` or other offset at the end.